# Eclipse EMF Feature Model Tool Can't find OR and Alternative

Tags: eclipse, emf

I'm trying to work with eclipse [EMF Feature Diagram Model Editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF_Feature_Model/Feature_Diagram_Editor), I'm able to right click individual lines and turn them from mandatory to optional, and back again, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use the **OR** or **Alternative** features which you can see in the key on the top right of the image below. It would be amazing if anyone knew how to do it as I've been racking my brain for ages trying to figure it out.

[image: Feature Model]

Answer (score 2):

Try to drop your new feature on the line  directory which has already drawn between parent and child on the diagram. (Not to drop boxes) You could see OR and XOR menu by clicking the line!